# PyQt4 - list widget click event?

Tags: python, qt4, qlistwidget

im having a problem on my mini project.

i have a method here

```
def PrintClick(self,name = ""):
    print name
```

then i have a list widget named **lstStudents**

how do i call the method **PrintClick** when i click an item inside **lstStudents**?
also how do i pass the parameters?

i tried

```
self.connect(self.ui.lstStudents,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.PrintClick)
```

but i doest work.
please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually call the event when the list selection changes. Also, I'd use the new-style event signals. They look nicer:

```
self.ui.lstStudents.currentItemChanged.connect(self.PrintClick)
```

Comment: hi this works great, thank you.. but how do i pass a parameter? please help me on it too ty.

Comment: hi i already figure it out. thanks just use .text() to show the clicked item